# Finding a Patent of My Great Grandfather

Tags: research

I recently found out my Great Grandfather was an inventor and could possibly have received a patent. I am looking for genealogical reasons. How can I find it? I would date back to the later part of the 19th century.

Comment: If you provide his name and where he was from, we can help you search.

Comment: update us on this!

Comment: I have a similar situation, my great grandfather was an inventor and even had an automobile company in the early 1920's. I have found his patents on google but would like to know if they are still held by someone or expired. I have tried searching Public Pair and the links provided below but no luck. One is US1181111 A. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most old patent collections is that of Espacenet.

https://worldwide.espacenet.com/advancedSearch?locale=en_EP

Just type the name of your grandfather.

You can try the same search here:

https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/structuredSearch.jsf

If it's a US patent, it should be there ;)